# "Atomicity" in communication between two devices

Tags: android, communication

I'd like to send short data from device A (sender) to device B (receiver), 
in such way that **if device B will save** the data then   **device A must delete** it from its storage.

If B won't save or A won't delete  communication must be reverted (as if there ware no communication at all)

Communication is made over unstable channel so there is high possibility of it
to be broken at some part.

How should I approach this problem?

It can be in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An algorithm over TCP (reliable, ordered, error-checked delivery):

1. A sends the data to B
2. B saves the data
3. B sends OK to A
4. A deletes the data permanently
5. B just keep the data (doesn't delete it).

Exceptions:

- If some of the steps fails, do not execute the next.
- If B doesn't receive OK from A, B doesn't save data permanently.
- If A doesn't receive OK from B, A doesn't delete data permanently.

Detailing by node:

A

1. Sends data to B
2. Waits for OK
3. Receives OK
4. Delete data

B

1. Receives data
2. Saves data
3. Sends OK
4. Receives OK

Comment: Usually preserving the data is more important than making sure that only one device have it. So your approach is not fail safe in that sense. Suppose step 4 fail then we will loose the data permanently. So your algorithm will only work if we rather have no data than duplicated data (unlikely requirement)

Comment: If step 4 fails you will not execute step 5! No data lost.

Comment: A have to way to know it so it will DO 5

Comment: Of course you have. If you're using TCP the connection will fail if B didn't receives. It's TCP (reliable, ordered, error-checked delivery). And if you don't receive the OK by timeout, it is a failure and you must rollback.

Comment: If you assume A knows if B receive it or not then you have to assume that B know if A receive it. Then why even do 4? You only need 3 so A knows that B have no savng problem (such as hard disk fail)

Comment: Actually, you don't need steps 3 and 4 if your only worry is the network, because TCP will garantee it for you. But you can implement the acknowledgement (items 3 and 4) just to tell each part that they're ok while processing the request.

Comment: Step 4 is still not needed. As I explained, step 3 is indeed needed because A needs to know that B saved the data successfully. Step 4 does not provide anything. By the definition of the protocol A has to delete the data already.

Comment: You're rigth. Only if we change steps 4 and 5 it will have a reason to exist. Right?

Comment: If you want to confirm the deletion then yes. The last step then serve as a transaction complete confirmation. At any step the transaction could be cancel if anything wrong happen - and all party has to roll back.